# how to convert byte string to pdf to display it in Web view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, pdf, webview, base64, byte

I am calling a json API from which I am getting a pdf element , it looks like this , this file is only for example as it is corrupted but looks like this :

```
JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlbi1VUykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSbDQTRGRTNBQ0MxQTg5PjwxOTIzMDRGMTgwOTZCMzQ0QjExQ0E0RkUzQUNDMUE4OT5dIC9QcmV2IDk3NjgwL1hSZWZTdG0gOTY0MTg+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoxMDgzNzgNCiUlRU9G
```

I want to convert it into pdf to display it into web view in my application.

My tried Code:

```
String fileUrl = response.getPdf();
byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
         bytes = fileUrl.getBytes("UTF-8");
        Log.e("Byte Array",bytes.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It Converts into  [B@a4d4cef. After this i am not understanding what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: "It Converts into [B@a4d4cef" -- it converts into a `byte[]`. `toString()` on `Object` prints things like `[B@a4d4cef` if it is not overridden by a subclass. Note that `WebView` has no built-in ability to display a PDF.

Comment: So, what should i do?

Comment: Do about... what? If your concern is the `Log.e()` line, delete that line. Beyond that, save your PDF to a file and use `startActivity()` with `ACTION_VIEW` to allow the user to view the PDF with their preferred PDF viewer.